# Hemisphere containing the maximum number of points scattered on a sphere

Tags: computational-geometry, packing-and-covering, integer-programming

Consider a set of points $x_1, \ldots,x_n$ on $\mathbb{S}^{k-1}$ (the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^k$). The goal is finding the hemisphere which contains the maximum number of $x_i$'s. Basically, we would like to find the hyperplane passing through the origin, which contains the maximum number of $x_i$'s on one side. Any pointers to equivalent problems, or (in)exact algorithms?

Comment: If the points are in general position, there is a simple bruteforce algorithm in $O(n^k)$ time: simply consider all hemispheres that have their boundary aligned with a $(k-1)$-tuple of the points. Are you looking for some faster?

Comment: Yes, my preference is with faster algorithms, even if they are inexact. Also, the problem should have been considered before, but I yet have not found any relative content.

Comment: I guess a quick $O(n)$ heuristic would be to pick the hyperplane that is normal to the vector pointing from the origin to the center of mass. I can think of some pathologic configurations where this fails spectacularly, but for more generic configurations, it should yield a good first approximation.

Comment: @mlk: thank you. The problem with such approach, as you mentioned, is the pathological configurations which happen easily once we don't have a unimodal distribution of the directions. I was hoping of an algorithm that keeps including/excluding points until some type of convergence is reached.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4583251/hemisphere-containing-the-maximum-number-of-points-scattered-on-a-sphere

Comment: Another way to phrase your question: Find an optimal $2$-cluster partition via hyperplanes through the origin. This may help in searches.

Comment: Please do not post the same question simultaneously on both Math.SE and MO,
in order to avoid duplication of efforts.

Comment: @mlk I have tried your approach with random points placed on the sphere, but I was able to get much better results using other approaches including gradient ascent (faster), simulated annealing (slower), or evolutionary algorithms (slower).

Comment: Someone asked a question about equivalent to this again. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444144/how-to-solve-the-optimization-problem-max-mathbfw-sum-i-textsign-mathb/444160#444160 I wonder why this question was upvoted but closed the first time, but it attracted multiple answers, upvotes, and upvoted answers the second time. I think it is an interesting mathematical question even if is best solved using inexact algorithms..